# Where is this base64 code in my game coming from?

Tags: html, text, base64

I made a game called [2048 Bitcoin](https://www.2048bitcoin.tk/) and at the fully bottom, there is a base64 text saying **eFd3R0JJVFlEd0JjMzRTYXE2REhFR2t1NENldEJTbXE=**. When I write a paragraph at the end, the text is above the base64 code in case you want to know.

I have done an advanced search on my code trying to search where this is coming from, but I had no luck.

Answer (score 0):

A quick look at the HTML file shows what is causing it. At the bottom of the file, before `</body>` the base64 string. [source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oY9CW.png)

Comment: I am looking at my code and I still can’t find it. [picture](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/678951996551856160/1045365283633774633/EDE0C939-80B1-49A7-999E-0108B826DADB.png)